# Slick Carousal Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, carousel, typeerror

I have this script for a Slick Carousel within some Ajax Tabs and I keep getting the Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error, not quote sure what it's referring to?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 7000
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you included the slick carousel plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of jquery is included and that there is only one instance. I've ran into this issue too and was able to fix it by upgrading my jquery.